# Illustrator: Rotate list round each center

Tags: adobe-illustrator, rotate

There is ideas, how to rotate a lot of objects around their each center?

[image: rotate each of this number 90 deg now 1 by 1]

Comment: Which objects are you asking about here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transform every item in group without affecting the group](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79898/transform-every-item-in-group-without-affecting-the-group)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually quite easy:

1. Select all the objects you want to rotate.
2. Right click, and select *Transform > Transform each...*.
3. Enter the wanted *Angle* and click *OK*.

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is solution for my questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- Select one object and convert it to a **Symbol**
- Repeat with all the objects
- Select one of the repeated symbols and the *original symbol* thumbnail at the **Symbol Panel**
- From the **Symbol Panel** options menu choose **Replace Symbol**
- Do the same with the others
- If everything is right, when choosing **Select Unused** from the **Symbol Panel** options menu the only one unselected will be the original symbol
- Edit the *original symbol* clicking twice and rotate it

[image: Symbol replacing]

Comment: You can select multiple ones

Comment: This is not my collision but, it can be like one of the solution.
I have about 400 copies of this logo.